# Get package source from sources.list.d

Tags: ubuntu, packaging

I want to download source for suricata package

I do add following repo

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oisf/suricata-stable
```

If I install package I get latest version

```
$ suricata -V
This is Suricata version 6.0.4 RELEASE
```

But when I try downloading source

```
$ apt source suricata
Reading package lists... Done
NOTICE: 'suricata' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
https://alioth.debian.org/anonscm/git/pkg-suricata/pkg-suricata.git
Please use:
git clone https://alioth.debian.org/anonscm/git/pkg-suricata/pkg-suricata.git
to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
Need to get 11.8 MB of source archives.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe suricata 3.2-2ubuntu3 (dsc) [2,768 B]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe suricata 3.2-2ubuntu3 (tar) [11.7 MB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe suricata 3.2-2ubuntu3 (diff) [20.3 kB]
Fetched 11.8 MB in 1s (10.3 MB/s)   
dpkg-source: info: extracting suricata in suricata-3.2
dpkg-source: info: unpacking suricata_3.2.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking suricata_3.2-2ubuntu3.debian.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: applying reproducible.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying debian-default-cfg.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying optional-hyperscan.patch
$ ls
suricata-3.2  suricata_3.2-2ubuntu3.debian.tar.xz  suricata_3.2-2ubuntu3.dsc  
suricata_3.2.orig.tar.gz
```

I get old version.

Is there a way to fetch source from newly added repo?

I did look into the git repo already, but I am more interested in the actual command of `apt source` or something similar.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was totally wrong so I deleted it. GAD3R's answer seems to be correct. And I edited your question to mention what you've already tried, which is recommended for any question you ask on SO. See [ask] for more tips. BTW, check out the [tour] if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe suricata 3.2-2ubuntu3 (dsc) [2,768 B]
```

will tell you from where the package has been downloaded, it is from `universe` repository.

You need to enable the source package for the added PPA:

```
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/oisf/suricata-stable/ubuntu bionic main" |
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oisf-suricata-stable-bionic.list
sudo apt update
apt source suricata
```

Comment: Thanks,  this worked and understood what was main issue: $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oisf-ubuntu-suricata-stable-bionic.list 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oisf/suricata-stable/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/oisf/suricata-stable/ubuntu bionic main
the source was commented out